# HTTPS urllib.request,read into JSON

Tags: python

If I go for example from [urlib2](https://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/urllib2.html)

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/')
html = response.read()
```

then it works fine.

I was suprised to see that my code

```
req = urllib.request.Request('https://www.tehnomanija.rs/it-shop/laptop-racunari')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
data = json.loads(the_page)
print (data)
```

produces error like this

```
         data = json.loads(the_page)
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Except the other protocol I do not see why this would not work.

Comment: Keep in mind this URL doesn't even return a JSON string. Anyway this will be much easier using `requests`: `import requests  ;  data = requests.get(url).json()`

Comment: @DeepSpace OK,I understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json.load()` is for loading from file. You need `json.loads()`:

```
data = json.loads(the_page)
```

Comment: You will need to use `the_page.decode()`. Anyway this URL doesn't even return a JSON so it will break anyhow